# How can I connect an Arduino / ESP8266 to an Azure MySQL database?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am currently trying to connect an ESP8266 to my Azure MySQL database via WiFi, but have not yet been successful.

I have tried a bunch of guides, but no luck and I'm running out of ideas. I have made a connection to an IoT Hub in Azure but could not forward the messages to the MySQL database in the cloud. I managed to get it stored in a blob datatype but had so many issues with it that I kinda scratched that idea.

Last thing I tried was trying to implement the example from 
https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino
more specifically the 'connect_wifi' example. I was unable to find the ip of my azure server so i tried using some of the code from the 'connect_by_hostname' but no luck there.

I'm new to Arduino and cloud in general so any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you can get it stored at all, but not in sql, then it's not really an arduino question. typically you hit some http gateway that does all the fancy stuff like DBs for you.

Comment: How would I go about let's say getting the blob type files which are stored in a storage account in my Azure server sent to my SQL DB (also in the azure cloud) using http gateway?

Comment: usually a small snip of php or something like that, that listens on the URL then makes backend calls to the services mentioned once there's something for it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would directly connect with an C++ embedded file. One way you could achieve this is by creating a computer application and connect to the machine via Bluetooth.

```
{Arduino}
* Intake information
* Process into commands
* Push through software serial ----(Blue Tooth-----> { PC or MAC}
                                                    *Create C# or Swift App
                                                    *Intake information via COM-PORT
                                                    *Prepare SQL command with serial data
                                                    *Push to database server
```

This may of not of been the method you were looking for, but it's a way I found around the issue when working with Azure Databases and Arduino Micro-Controllers. An alternative is going to Raspberry Pi which has a little more resources to deal with server functions.

Hope this helps.